# How to print specific json list items?

Tags: python, arrays, json

I'm making a python bot and the response is coming back as 
JSON.

Here is a quick show of what it brings back:

```
[["Message","User string from here."]]
```

So first what I've done is, loaded the `json` from the python module `json`.

```
json.loads(resp)
```

and it brings back:

```
[[u"Message",u"user string from here"]]
```

How do I print out the Message which will return the value `user string from here`?

Comment: `print(json.loads(resp)[0][1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json

raw_response = '[["Message","User string from here."]]'
data = json.loads(raw_response)

print(data[0][1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will give it a go :)

Comment: @АлексейЛагунов, glad I culd help :). In that case, could you accept so that the question will be marked as answered?

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads` converts json into the native datatypes of python. So, when you did `json.loads(resp)`, you get back a list of lists.

You can simply iterate over the list to access whatever elements you want.

In your case, `print json.loads(resp)[0][1]` should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'll give it a shot.